# How many calls to the RSA encryption function E(m) necessary to encrypt an R × C-pixel image using this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, rsa

I am self-studying an Algorithms course on MITOpencourseware. Sometimes I get stuck on a problem and have no way of solving my doubts. I cannot understand how to solve the following problem related to encrypting an image using RSA:

> A picture has RxC pixels (R rows, C columns). Each pixel is
> represented by 3 bytes that are RGB color space coordinates. This
> picture should be encrypted using RSA. The public key is (e, n), where
> n is an N-byte number. An inefficient encryption method would process
> each row of pixel data as follows:
>
> 1.Break the 3C bytes of pixel data into groups of N − 1 bytes
>
> 2.Pad the last group with 0 bytes up to N − 1 bytes
>
> 3.Encrypt each group of N − 1 bytes to obtain an N-byte output
>
> 4.Concatenate the N-byte outputs
>
> **How many calls to the RSA encryption function E(m) are necessary to encrypt an R × C-pixel image?**

The solution is that the exact number of calls is

> R*[C/(N-1)]

where those brackets should actually be ceiling function brackets. **How is this result reached?**

Comment: one, because you wouldn't encrypt an image with multiple calls to RSA. Use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: Right, but hypothetically, using the inefficient encryption method described above, how would one calculate the number of calls?

Comment: Are you sure that his is the solution? I expect to see a 3 in there somewhere.

Comment: Here is the link to the entire problem set with solutions: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_006F11_ps5_sol.pdf

Comment: The problem in question is on page 12 and 13, and yes, the solution is as I wrote initially, unless the solution to the problem set is wrong.

Comment: I would say, the solution is missing a 3 as in `R*[3*C/(N-1)]`, but the Landau-Notation is still correct.

Comment: if the solution has a three in it then it is a mystery no more.